Symbol "^" inside math mode
I wanna to do sommething like:
(m\n)|^m
but i can't write symbol ^ inside math mode.
\text{^} or \text{\^} also didn't work

I just tried inside LyX to see what LaTeX code it produces and it gives $\mathcircumflex$. Does that do what you need?

Would \hat{\phantom{x}} do?

\text{\textasciicircum}?

Works both variants. Not exactly a "^", but better, than nothing

@scottkosty didn't work. Maybe some missed libraries?

Where did you find (in a math book or paper) ^ used as a binary operation symbol? Can you please be more specific about what you're trying to achieve?

Maybe what you want is a logical and symbol.

@Sigur defenetly not

@egreg i m trying to use it as exponential.
Something like:
2a=4b | / c
a = 2b
not "2a/c", but "2a^c"

Why not the good old and standard exponential notation? By the way, the example you show isn't very clear.

It seems like you're trying to write a set of equations with instructional information showing an operation on the right hand side. For this you can be more verbose and write \text{Raise to the power $m$}.

One option would be to load the ^ symbol from the text font and set the catcode of the ^ input character to other (12).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{textfont}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{u}
\DeclareMathSymbol{^}{\mathord}{textfont}{"5E}
\catcode`\^=12
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  a^b
\end{equation*}
\end{document}


